# Result of storing a value larger than 8 bits into an 8 bit register

Tags: assembly, x86

I'd like to know what happens when you try to store a value that is too large for an 8 bit register into an 8 bit register.

What happens to the upper 8 bits? Is this data lost, or does it shift into bx for instance? Does the mov instruction care, or will it just store 00ffh into al as a result?

Example:

```
xor bl,bl
add bl,0fffh
mov al,bl
```

Comment: Ideally the assembler would prevent your from doing that since it's a non-encodable instruction.

Comment: `add bl,ffffh` doesn't exist

Comment: Changed it to 0fffh. I compiled using this command:

nasm -f elf ch1.asm

Compiler threw a warning:

ch1.asm:21: warning: byte data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]

Comment: It isn't encodable however some assemblers have been known to truncate to the required size with a warning and some have been known to do it silently. Most assemblers will generate a hard error. Ah I see you are using NASM. NASM is giving a warning by default. What it did was truncated 0ffffh to the lower bits 0ffh and stored that in the 8 bit register.

Comment: To make it clear, the cpu never sees your constant which is too big, so it's not the `mov` instruction doing some magic at runtime.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to expect that with most assemblers, it will produce a hard error or automatically truncate it as you said?

Comment: Apparently the version of NASM that you are using treats it as a warning by deafult. You could have it treated as an error by assembling with `-Werror=number-overflow` (or simply `-Werror`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Truncation to `add bl, 0xff` happens at assemble time.**  (Or you get an assemble-time error if you use NASM `-Werror=number-overflow` or `-Werror`)

x86 machine code has no encodings with immediates wider than the operand-size; that would be redundant and a waste of space.  e.g. `add r/m8, imm16` doesn't exist, only `imm8`.  See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add for the available encodings.

If you want to think of it as sign-extending to 32-bit and then truncating to the destination width, that's fine because it doesn't change the result.  But such mental gymnastics are probably not helpful.

The operand-size of the instruction is set at 8 bits by the destination register being an 8-bit register in the asm source.  So the assembler will choose the 8-bit `add` opcode.  Thus when the CPU decodes it, the operand-size is set by the opcode, not by the immediate data or the result of the add.

> Does the mov instruction care, or will it just store 00ffh into al as a result?

I can see how you're imagining that `add` might widen and affect BH as well, but I don't see how this would make *any* sense.

It's a separate instruction.

This is assembly language; every instruction is assembled separately and (logically) runs separately in program order, having its specified effect on the architectural state of the machine.

(Real x86 CPUs do parallel / out-of-order execution, but keep track of everything to maintain the illusion that instructions run in order one at a time.  This is the hardware equivalent of the C/C++ "as-if" rule.)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I appreciate the insight.